# ranking based on multiple tables

Tags: mysql

```
select a.no, a.Dtime,count(b.Dtime)+1 as Rank 
from table1 a left 
join table1 b on a.Dtime>b.Dtime and a.no=b.no 
group by a.no,a.Dtime 
order by a.no, a.Dtime
```

table1 Input:

```
NO  Dtime
1   08:10:00
1   09:10:00
1   09:40:00
1   10:10:00
2   09:30:00
2   10:15:00
3   09:00:00
```

Output:

```
NO  Dtime       Rank
1   08:10:00    1
1   09:10:00    2
1   09:40:00    3
1   10:10:00    4
2   09:30:00    1
2   10:15:00    2
3   09:00:00    1
```

But I am looking for Output in mysql where table2 Rank links to table1 and table2 Dtime i.e. table1.Dtime>table2.time

table2 Input

```
NO  Dtime   
1   08:30:00    
1   09:15:00    
1   09:50:00    
2   08:30:00    
2   09:45:00    
3   09:50:00
```

Output:

```
NO  table1.Dtime    Rank    table2.Dtime
1   08:10:00        0       00:00:00 
1   09:10:00        1       08:30:00
1   09:40:00        2       09:15:00
1   10:10:00        3       09:50:00
2   09:30:00        1       08:30:00
2   10:15:00        2       09:45:00
3   09:00:00        0       00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach with your initial query. Just `left join` to `table2`. To get the `Dtime` from `table2` you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.no, a.Dtime,
       count(b.Dtime) as Rank,
       coalesce((select c.Dtime
       from table2 as c       
       where c.no = a.no and a.Dtime > c.Dtime
       order by c.Dtime desc limit 1), '00:00:00') as t2Dtime
from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.Dtime > b.Dtime and a.no = b.no 
group by a.no,a.Dtime 
order by a.no, a.Dtime
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/581efc/4)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Betsos